# What does & mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand an example from [plotlyhs](https://glutamate.github.io/plotlyhs/):

```
plotly "div6"
    [points (aes & x .~ sepalLength 
                 & y .~ sepalWidth
                 & color ?~ (fromEnum . irisClass)) iris]
    & layout . margin ?~ thinMargins
    & layout . height ?~ 300
```

But I don't know what `&` means. Also I can't quite seem to google it.

I don't know what `.~` or `?~` mean, either, but I guess I ask other questions for those.

Comment: It looks like it's defined in `Lens.Micro`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens-0.4.8.3/docs/Lens-Micro.html#v:-38-

Comment: See the haskell tag info section, "What is function foo / operator #$*?": https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info . Those are operators that come from one of the imported libraries. You can find out which by reading the documentation, or asking ghci, e.g. after loading the example and doing `:info (&)` or `:info (?~)`

Comment: [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a great tool to find the answers to these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 5):

More than likely, you're using the [reverse function application operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-), defined as

```
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
a & f = f a
```

It's simply a flipped version of `($)`, frequently used in GUI libraries and other things where it makes sense to "apply" features and modifiers to existing values.

```
textbox & onClick foo & enabled
```

looks better and is often more straightforward than

```
enabled . onClick foo $ textbox
```

which reads backwards, in some sense. To know what the line is about, you have to start from the right.

Comment: The definition is so terse it's criminal to refer to it only as flipped application: `a & f = f a`

Comment: Thanks for adding it, I should have qualified with  ‘almost criminal’ ;)

Comment: I was secretly hoping that GHC did some bizarre compiler optimization so that `a & f` was not defined exactly as `f a` but it seems that [it truly is that simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.Function.html#%26).